# i want to fetch all data which is in my timeline but it is returning either first or last. DjangoRestMultipleModels

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

i have two models from which i want to fetch details for a particular user i am using **DjangoRestMultipleModels** querylist is inside for loop but it is returning only one data either first or last

```
class UserTimelineAPIView(MultipleModelAPIView):
    def get_queryList(self):
        user = self.request.user.id
        obj = SubscriberFollower.objects.filter(user=user)
        for ab in obj:
            queryList = [
                (Post.objects.filter(institute_id=ab.institute.id), PostSerializer),
                (Event.objects.filter(institute=ab.institute.id, active=True), EventSerializer),
            ]
        return queryList
```

Comment: Your `queryList` variable is being overwritten in every iteration of the for loop. It isn't clear what your desired outcome is, so I can't provide any code suggestions, but I'm guessing you want to append that list of tuples to a list rather than declare a new list of tuples with every iteration.

Comment: yes i used `append`and `extend` but these are not helpful for me

Comment: What is your desired outcome, in terms of the data structure that you are trying to produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `DjangoRestMultipleModels` wants to receive a list of tuples, one for each model. In that case you could use a list comprehension to produce one queryset per model including all the objects you want. 
Try this:

```
obj = SubscriberFollower.objects.filter(user=user)
institutes = [ab.institute for ab in obj]
queryList = [
    (Post.objects.filter(institute__in=institutes), PostSerializer),
    (Event.objects.filter(institute__in=institutes, active=True), EventSerializer),
]
```

A more efficient way to do it would be to use the `values_list` queryset method.

```
institute_ids = SubscriberFollower.objects.filter(user=user).values_list('institute__id', flat=True)
queryList = [
    (Post.objects.filter(institute__id__in=institute_ids), PostSerializer),
    (Event.objects.filter(institute__id__in=institute_ids, active=True), EventSerializer),
]
```